# Convert a response object to entity in spring boot resttemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am calling an endpoint that returns back a JSON response.
Here is sample of the JSON response:

```
{
    "main": {
        "test":{
            "Date": "2022-06-06",
            "Id": 1234
        },
        "response" :[
            {
            "responseTime": 100,
            "redirects": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code to get the JSON response:

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(setHeaders());
            ResponseEntity<Main> response = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.GET, request, Main.class);
```

I want to convert the response to an entity object, with the response section being a HashMap. I tried the following but I get an error that the conversion failed

```
public class Main {
    private Test test;
    private Response response;
}

public class Test{
  private Date Date;
  private int Id;
}

public class Response{
private Map<String, String> responseMap;
}
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide the error?

Comment: Besides the error. your JSON Response `response` is not a map. It is an array of objects with the properties `responseTime` and `redirects`. So your Response Java class should contain a List of the Type containing these properties

Comment: Hasmap JSON should like like: `response: {key: value, key2: value}`

Comment: also, what you are getting back is an object containing a `main` object. You are trying to push in the received json into `main` when you have ccompletely missed that `main`itself is inside an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are getting back is an `Object` containing a `main` object

```
{
    "main": {
        "test":{
            "Date": "2022-06-06",
            "Id": 1234
        },
        "response" :[
            {
            "responseTime": 100,
            "redirects": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

which means

```
// Can be named whatever
public class Response {
    private Main main;

    //constructor, getter setters
}

public class Main {
    private Test test;
    private ArrayList<Data> response;

    //constructor, getter setters
}

public class Test {
    private LocalDate date;
    private int id;

    //constructor, getter setters
}

public class Data {
    private int responseTime;
    private int redirects;

    //constructor, getter setters
}
```

And then you call and plase the response data in the top level object

```
ResponseEntity<Main> response = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.GET, request, Response.class);
```

Comment: That was it, i was missing the outer object. The attributes inside response is not fixed, so I cannot create an entity for it and that I why I was thinking of using a Hash Map but I guess that is not possible

Comment: it is not recommended to have undefined objects as this can be a security risk